# How can I disable LLMNR in systemd-resolved?

Tags: systemd, systemd-resolved

How can I disable LLMNR in `systemd-resolved`?

I tried adding: `LLMNR=no` to `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`

but when I type `systemd-resolve --status` it still shows

> LLMNR setting: yes

I have tried rebooting computer and restarting `systemd-resolved.service`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## There's a general LLMNR setting and a per link LLMNR setting

There's the LLMNR setting in `systemd-resolved` and there's also the per-link LLMNR setting in `systemd-networkd`.

The setting you're looking at in the `systemd-resolve --status` output is actually the one from `systemd-networkd`. Except that, if you're not running `systemd-networkd`, it will STILL show `LLMNR setting: yes`.

The default setting will show something like this:

```
Link 2 (ens3)
      Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
       LLMNR setting: yes
```

It also means `systemd-resolved` will be taking requests on UDP port 5355 (the LLMNR port), on these interfaces.

## Changing resolved.conf file will change "Current Scopes:" line

If you disable it by setting `LLMNR=no` in `resolved.conf` and restarting `systemd-resolved`, then you get:

```
Link 2 (ens3)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
```

You can see that the scope changed from `DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6` to just `DNS`. So it will use DNS only and will no longer take requests on UDP port 5355.

## Changing *.network file will change "LLMNR setting:" line

If you're also using `systemd-networkd`, you can further disable LLMNR on that interface, by setting `LLMNR=no` in the `[Network]` section of the `*.network` file for that interface.

For example:

```
# /etc/systemd/network/90-ens3-nollmnr.network
[Match]
Name=ens3

[Network]
LLMNR=no
```

After setting that and restarting `systemd-networkd`, the output of `systemd-resolve --status` will include:

```
Link 2 (ens3)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: no
```

## Summary

So, in short, `LLMNR setting: yes` just means that it wasn't **explicitly disabled on that interface**. And it can only be disabled on that interface if it's being managed by `systemd-networkd`. If you disable it through resolved itself, it will essentially have the same effect, but it will only show in the list of current scopes, and not really under `LLMNR setting`.

**NOTE**: Some pointers to the code showing that `LLMNR=yes` is the default setting [here](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v238/src/resolve/resolved-link.c#L54) and [here](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v238/src/resolve/resolved-link.c#L332).

Comment: dude thanks so much, you even linked the source code