# How can I disable LLMNR in Netplan?

Tags: networking, netplan, systemd-networkd

I found [How can I disable LLMNR in systemd-resolved?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025309/how-can-i-disable-llmnr-in-systemd-resolved) useful for demonstrating how to disable LLMNR in systemd-networkd. However, ubuntu 18.04 uses netplan to configure the network rather than systemd-networkd (which manages it instead). So this solution doesn't work.

How netplan works is it directly manipulates the `/run/systemd/network/*.network` files using the keys in the `/etc/netplan/*.yaml` files (please see documentation on netplan.io site). According to netplan, you can set the relevant keys in the yaml file in netplan to configure hosts the way you would have had you used systemd-networkd instead (via `/etc/systemd/network/`). But I see no keys to control the LLMNR setting per interface.

How can I continue using netplan to configure my network (ala systemd-networkd), and have this value in the run files generated by netplan to properly control this setting?

What doesn't work:

- Setting `LLMNR=no` to `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` (this is a global setting, running `systemd-resolve --status` still shows `LLMNR setting: yes`)
- Managing `/var/run/systemd/network/*.network` files after netplan has (they're dynamically created, so my changes are obliterated on reboot, service restart, etc)

Comment: (FYI: I'm managing several hundred hosts by generating the netplan yaml config on a control server, so high-maintenance configuration tasks that require lots of detailed specific information about a single host is less useful than a single setting I can apply across a hundred hosts).

Answer (score 2):

One solution has been proposed by Ryan Harper here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1777523

> You can create a .network file which will disable LLMNR on any interface like the following.
>
> /etc/systemd/network/10-disable-llmnr.network

```
[Match]
Name=*

[Network]
LLMNR=no
```

> That will apply to any network interface, you can modify the `[Match]` section to pick interfaces you choose. The `systemd-resolve --status` output will show that LLMNR setting is applied to the interfaces as well.

In my own tests however, this didn't work as well with static addresses already using the `[Match]` section.

Comment: Don't do this - LLMNR is disabled but all IPs are gone as personally experienced and as reported by others in https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1777523/comments/6, and if it's a remote server you may lose access to it

Comment: That was my comment. I'm the one who did that. And that wasn't because llmnr was disabled, it was because the file was misnamed. I did find another way to disable llmnr, it's just very inconvenient, and it doesn't make ips disappear. See this comment for the update about that: https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1777523/comments/8

Comment: thanks for heads up; please consider updating the answer.

Answer (score 1):

To disable LLMNR, add the following to `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`:

```
[Resolve]
LLMNR=false
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work. 1) that only changes the global setting, not the per-interface setting which is still on by default, and 2) that's not a netplan file.

Comment: Note: my question specifically asks how to fix this in 1) a way that works, and 2) not this way.